# having problems Trying to append elements to each other

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a to-do list. When the form is submitted, it adds an li element that has a label containing an input tag and an image tag.

But it only adds the li element.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
const formT = document.querySelector(`[data-new-todo-form]`)
const inputT = document.querySelector(`[data-new-todo-input]`)
const todoList = document.getElementById('todo-list');
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

formT.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    
    let todoName = inputT.value
    if(todoName == null || todoName === '') {
        return ('enter a Valid text');
    } else {
        const todo = document.createElement('li')
        const todoLabel = document.createElement('label')
        const todoInput = document.createElement('input')
        const todoImage = document.createElement('img')
        todoImage.src = "/images/icon-check.svg";
        todoInput.type = 'checkbox'
        todoInput.id = 'completed'
        todoInput.classList.add('todoInput')
        todoLabel.classList.add('todoLabel')
        todoLabel.htmlFor = 'completed'
        todoLabel.appendChild(todoInput)
        todoLabel.appendChild(todoImage)
        todo.appendChild(todoLabel)
        todo.innerText = todoName
        fragment.appendChild(todo)
        todoList.appendChild(fragment)
        inputT.value = null
    }
})
```

Comment: `todo.innerText = todoName` overwrites any elements you already appended to `todo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and

```
todo.innerText = todoName
```

This line overwrites the element you created above. So if you comment out the line, you will be able to check that the checkbox element is actually created.

```
todoLabel.appendChild(todoInput)
todoLabel.appendChild(todoImage)
const t = document.createTextNode(todoName);
todoLabel.appendChild(t);
```

So instead of using todo.innerText, create text node first with createTextNode and append the element to todoLabel element(or to the element you were intending to).